# Is using fusion on units to get them to Level 4 efficient?

Tags: world-at-arms

Is using fusion on units in World at Arms (Android + iOS) to get them to Level 4 efficient? It only doubles the stats of Level 3 troops, while increasing the price over 10 times. Also, the average player won't produce 96 troops just to have 6 Level 4 troops in all of their battle slots. Is there any overpowering advantage to having a Level 4 troop instead of just two Level 3 troops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Against 'novice' and 'casual' attacks you can do with level 3 units but when up against tougher opponents you've gotta deploy the best 6. If u have a level 3 unit of attack say 50 u will end up lining six units with an attack total of 50*6=300 points.
And one more thing worth noting is that as you go further u will find that when level 3 units are fused they don't just double up.. at times it is 1.25 times which counts a lot for unit with high attack point.
But since they deplete so make sure you deploy your level 4 only when u need them.
My advice use level 3 till they are about to exhaust and then fuse them!

Comment: Interesting! I never considered using the level 3 units almost all the way up and then fusing them.